# Using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit, prove $\lim_{x \to a} (3f(x)-5g(x)) = 3\lim_{x \to a} f(x) -5\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

The $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $ \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist. Using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit, prove $\lim_{x \to a} (3f(x)-5g(x)) = 3\lim_{x \to a} f(x) -5\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$

I think I know how to solve this, but I have a question about whether I need to include a step… here is my work.

Given:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \delta_{\epsilon}’ > 0 \space \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \space 0<|x-a| < \delta_{\epsilon}’ \space |f(x)-L| < \epsilon
$$

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \delta_{\epsilon}’’ > 0 \space \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \space 0<|x-a| < \delta_{\epsilon}’’ \space |g(x) - M| < \epsilon
$$

Now for my question. Do I write

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \delta_{\epsilon} > 0 \space \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \space 0<|x-a| < \delta_{\epsilon} \space |3f(x) - 5g(x) - (3L- 5M)|< \epsilon
$$

Or
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \space \exists \delta_{\epsilon} > 0 \space \forall x\in \mathbb{R} \space 0<|x-a| < \delta_{\epsilon} \space |3f(x) - 5g(x) - (L - M)|< \epsilon
$$

If I use the second, then do I first need to show that $lim_{x\to a} 3f(x) = 3lim_{x\to a} f(x)$? If I use the first method then I think I can just choose

$\delta_{\epsilon} = min(\frac{\epsilon}{6}, \frac{\epsilon}{10})$

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You said you think you know how to solve but then you ask which expression should work?  Well, which one gave you the correct solution?  One of them will works and the limit goes to the correct value, the other will *fail* to prove int goes to something else.

Comment: "If I use the second, then do I first need to show that limx→a3f(x)=3limx→af(x)? "  Worse.  If you use the second you would have to show that $\lim_{x\to a}3f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$.  Which you can't show because it is not true.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former one it should be. The reason is that now you are proving that the limit of a function $3f(x)+5g(x)$ at $a$ is $3L+5M$. If $L,M$ are limits of $f,g,$ respectively at $a$.

The second statement means that the limit of the above function is $L+M$.

Comment: Not only that, but the second statement would be impossible to show as it simply is not true.

Comment: Right, if $L,M$ are limits of $f,g,$ respectively at $a$.

Comment: Presumably they are.  If they weren't, the "Given" statements would not be true.